# How I can embed an image to a URL that will appear when I share the link

Tags: html

I am new to web development and everything has been exciting so far. I recently learned how to include meta tag, description, and favicon in HTML. But is there a tag for embedding an image to a URL that will appear when I share the link with somebody? For example, when I share a Youtube video link with somebody on Whatsapp,a banner of that video would appear along with the link and descriptions. How can I do something like this on my HTML website?

Just to be clear, I have uploaded the HTML website to Cpanel and it's active.

Comment: whatsapp has built-in function to check whether your chat message contains a URL to a website, and will display a thumbnail of the youtube movie if the URL is a youtube link. It is nothing to do with standard HTML.

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this thing in your web pages you have to include `open-graph` and `twitter-card` meta information in your every webpage.

After including these, when someone shares your link anywhere your webpage card will be rendered.

#### Open-graph Meta Tags

```html
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your site name" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Your site title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Webpage description" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://images.example.com/example.png" />
```

#### Twitter Card Meta tags

```html
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Your webpage title" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Description goes here" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://example.com/" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://images.example.com/example.png" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was really helpful.